# Change a php if the file don't contains a word

Tags: php, html, contains

I've a form that when sent, open another php file. I would like to get the form informations, and create a table, but if someone write the some word that have in the table, the code should echo "sorry". The first part of the code is working, it get the form, and create a table in index.php, but when I create the same form, it send again :S How I change it?

```
<?

$original_list = file_get_contents("index.php");

$file = fopen("index.php","w") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$since = $_POST["since"];
$since2 = "<tr><td class=\"since\"> $since </td><br/>";

$user = $_POST["user"];
$user2 = "<td class=\"content\"> $user </td><br/>";

$due = $_POST["due"];
$due2 = "<td class=\"due\"> $due </td></tr>\n";

if (strpos("index.php","word") === true) {
     echo "Sorry"
}elseif ($_POST["since"] <> "");{
    fwrite($file,"$since2$user2$due2$original_list");
} 
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the contents of a PHP file?  If you need the code from another file, just include it.

Comment: Could you please explain why / what you are trying to solve, because I am sure there are better ways. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: strops returns integer or false, so `===true` will never happen. You were probably looking for `!==false`, but the bigger question remains, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @PeeHaa If I wasn't suspended from the chat room, I would be talking with you about something :/

Answer (score 2):

change this line:

```
if (strpos("index.php","word") === true) {
```

to

```
if (strpos($original_list,"word") !== false) {
```

> strpos() Return Values
>
> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, as you aren't looking the file contents :

```
<?

$original_list = file_get_contents("index.php");

$file = fopen("index.php","w") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$since = $_POST["since"];
$since2 = "<tr><td class=\"since\"> $since </td><br/>";

$user = $_POST["user"];
$user2 = "<td class=\"content\"> $user </td><br/>";

$due = $_POST["due"];
$due2 = "<td class=\"due\"> $due </td></tr>\n";

if (strpos($original_list,"word") ) {  // <- this is the changed line
      echo "Sorry"
}elseif ($_POST["since"] <> "");{
    fwrite($file,"$since2$user2$due2$original_list");
} 
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: strpos() not returnes true!

Comment: oh yes, corrected it, sorry didn't your answer nor your comment :) thank you anyway